# Chamada WCF com AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, wcf

Preciso fazer a chamada ajax em uma página html que vai acionar uma aplicação WCF

Contrato WCF

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IMailingService
{
    [OperationContract]
    ServiceRetorno<string> ValidarParceiro(string login, string senha);
}

[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
    public class ControleMailingService : IMailingService
    {
        public ServiceRetorno<string> ValidarParceiro(string login, string senha)
        {

            ServiceRetorno<string> ret = new ServiceRetorno<string>();
            try
            {
                using (MailingData data = new MailingData())
                {
                    ret.Sucesso = data.ValidarParceiro(login, senha);
                    if (!ret.Sucesso)
                        ret.Mensagem = "Usuário ou senha inválido";
                    else
                        ret.DadosRetorno = CriarToken(login);
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                ret.Sucesso = false;
                ret.Mensagem = "Falha ao validar login: " + ex.Message;
            }
            return ret;
        }
}
```

CONFIGURAÇÃO ENDPOINT

```
      <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="MailingService_Endpoint" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
            maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="WcfVisualFix.MailingService">
        <endpoint binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="MailingService_Endpoint"
          name="MailingService_Endpoint" contract="WcfVisualFix.IMailingService" />
        <endpoint binding="webHttpBinding" address="" 
          behaviorConfiguration="MailingServiceAjaxBehavior" contract="WcfVisualFix.IMailingService" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="MailingServiceAjaxBehavior">
          <enableWebScript />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="false"  minFreeMemoryPercentageToActivateService="0" />

  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
  </system.webServer>
```

CHAMADA AJAX

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#btnAcessar").click(function(){

 $.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "http://visualfix.dyndns-web.com:93/MailingService.svc/ValidarParceiro",
data: { "login" : $("#txtUsuario").val(), "senha": $("#txtSenha").val() },
contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
dataType: "json",
success: 
 function (res) {
if(res.Sucesso)
 $("#txtToken").val(res.DadosRetorno);
else
 $("#txtToken").val(res.Mensagem);
 },
error: 
 function (err) {
alert(err.responseJSON);
 }
 });

});
});
```

A chamada retorna erro statusCode 0.

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://visualfix.dyndns-web.com:93/MailingService.svc/ValidarParceiro. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 400.

Efetuando teste pelo SOAP UI funciona corretamente.

Answer (score 0):

essa questão vc pode configurar no web config os acessos que o heade do serviço terá, no JS realmente ele vai bugar porque provavelmente vc não especificou nada na tag no web config.

Da uma olhada nesse poste ai que vc entenderá bem.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

e explicando um pouco mais:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636611/how-does-access-control-allow-origin-header-work

Comment: Pelo que pude entender, é necessário configurar um o Access Control no WCF para habilitar requisções de diferentes origems. Mas não esta claro pra mim se isso deve ser configurado através de ENDPOINT ou na codificação do método. No link2, esta desta maneira:  WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

Comment: A requisição pode ser feita através de AJAX? O exemplo do link1 esta utilizando XMLHttpRequest